# iOS push notification click causes app to crash

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, onesignal

I am having an issue with my push notification click. Everytime user clicks on the notifications, the app will crash instead of redirecting user to the specified page.

This part of the code is causing an error **"Could not cast value of type 'appname.LaunchScreenController' to 'UINavigationController'"**
:

`let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController`

And this code will cause **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** :

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    //receive the notifications
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "MyNotificationType"), object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewsController") as! NewsViewController
    let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
    rootViewController.pushViewController(vc, animated:true)
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

RootViewController is subclass of `UIViewController` not a `UINavigationController` You have to handle your `null` values

change to

```
let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController
```

Comment: I notice that but I would like to access the 'pushViewController' function which is a member of  UINavigationController. Hence, Im using UINavigationController.

Comment: Is your application embedded with UINavigationController?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm really new to this. What does it mean embedded? I have edited my question, with the error log.

Comment: that mean navigation based application or tab based application, which one you are following, Where are you setting rootviewcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

I change the code to this and it works just fine now

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "MyNotificationType"), object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewsController") as! NewsViewController
    let nav  = UINavigationController()
    nav.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

}
```